# Nuget vs Multi-repo solution for Microservices shared libraries

Tags: .net, architecture, nuget, microservices

**Story:**

1. We have a lot of `microservices` and communication happens mostly through `Service Bus` by sending `serialized DTOs`.
2. Some microservices `share the DB`, so entity `models`, for now, are `duplicated` in each microservice.

**Problems:**

1. Whenever we want to `modify DTO` which is used for communication between microservice we need to `modify it in each microservice`.
2. Any `change in the shared DB` requires making `changes in all related microservices` and single DB field edit causes `multiple PRs`.

**Possible solutions:**

Move any shared code to other repositories (DTOs repo, Entity Models repo, etc.), and create solutions with `Class Library projects`.

I have two approaches after this point:

- Create `NuGets` and add them to microservices.
- Add `bare Class Library projects` as a reference for all microservices and we'll get `Multi-repo solutions` with microservices.

**Pros/Cons:**

For `NuGets` I see mostly cons:

- It will require some `extra infrastructure` built around it to create artifacts.
- `To test any change` it will be needed to modify Nuget Solution, trigger some CI pipeline and `wait to build the NuGet` itself, update the microservice with a test version of `NuGet`, and only after that we can test the microservice itself.
- If `any errors` occur - `repeat an entire process`.

For `bare Class Library projects` I see mostly advantages:

- `VS 2022` brought some nice `support for Multi-repo` solutions.
- It will be possible to make `changes in shared projects` and `immediately test` them with actual microservices.

**Questions:**

- Could you add any pros/cons for my `possible solutions`?
- Could you recommend any other solutions for problems (with pros/cons)?

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer for your question, at least a full one, but few things to think about:

I would recommend to start deeper and look into pros and cons for monorepository vs multirepositories which has been discussed many times (for example [here](https://github.com/joelparkerhenderson/monorepo-vs-polyrepo) or [here](https://www.gitkraken.com/blog/git-multi-repo-vs-git-mono-repo)) so go through those articles first.

> Whenever we want to modify DTO which is used for communication between microservice we need to modify it in each microservice.

In general case with correct design and versioning approach you don't need to modify DTOs in each microservice on every change (if that change is not relevant to that microservice), unless it is a breaking change and breaking changes should be done as rare as possible and should be handled via versioning.

Another thing you can try looking into - using schema registry to define shared contracts and add it to every project via [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) and write some kind of generator to build DTOs automatically from it.

> Any change in the shared DB requires making changes in all related microservices and single DB field edit causes multiple PRs.

I would argue that shared database in microservice architecture is a huge antipattern which should be addressed as soon as possible (and yes, I understand that life is not always ideal and does not always align with patterns) and fixing it will remove quite a lot of your current problems, so I would suggest to concentrate on it (if it is possible/feasible) rather then on fixing the symptoms.

Also you can look into replicating somehow the [VMR which .NET team is shifting to](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/241).

As for the actual question for "Bare Class Library projects" and VS multi-repo support - first of all currently multi-repo support is limited only [to 10 repos](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/multi-repository-support-released/#10-repository-limit), and not everyone is using VS (for example because it is not available on Linux ATM), secondary there is a question of setting up build servers to work with this (which would be easier with nugets).

Answer (score 2):

> To test any change it will be needed to modify Nuget Solution, trigger some CI pipeline and wait to build the NuGet itself, update the microservice with a test version of NuGet, and only after that we can test the microservice itself.

You could create a local nuget source and put your locally packed nuget in there.

Just be mindful of the nuget cache. If you want to update your nuget package and still use the same version, you should remove it from `http-cache` first.
The location can be obtained via `dotnet nuget locals --list http-cache` or `NUGET_HTTP_CACHE_PATH` env variable.